# JavaScript injection into WebView not working on Android 2.3.6

Tags: java, android, android-webview

the problem I'm having is injecting some JavaScript into a WebView. I only have this problem on Android version 2.3.6 and below I'm assuming, don't have a test device lower than that though. My code works fine in Android 4+ so I'm not quite sure why it's failing. It seems to "submit" the form but doesn't fill out the username and password field in 2.3.6 so it always fails. My main goal is to simulate a form fill-out and submit in a WebView with two EditTexts so the user doesn't have to interact with the WebView itself. When the user hits the login button it runs this code:

```
    //Set what needs to be filled out in the WebView
    String javaScript = "(function(){ " +
        "document.getElementById('user').value = '" + mUsername + "'; " +
        "document.getElementById('password').value = '" + mPassword + "'; " +
        "document.getElementById('form').submit(); " +
        "})()";
    //Load the javascript here
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: " + javaScript);
```

I'm also setting my WebView settings to this:

```
    //Setup the WebView options/settings
    ...
    mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ...
```

I've tried searching for any reason why this wouldn't work on 2.3.6 but haven't come up with anything. Is there some restriction in version 2.* that isn't present in 4+?

Edit: The button that runs the above code is only enabled once the page is finished loading. So when this button is clicked the above JS injection is run.

```
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        ...
        //Only allow the user to inject the JS when the page has loaded
        if(url.equals("...")
            button.setEnabled(true);
        ...
    }
```

SOLUTION: I'm not sure if this actually was the cause but changing the single quotes in the JS code to use double quotes seemed to make it run. Something like:

```
    String javaScript = ... + "document.getElementById(\"user\").value = \"" + mUsername + "\"; "
```

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any restrictions that I'm aware of but it's not uncommon to encounter issues stemming from differing Javascript engines in various versions of Android.  It is likely simply a matter of trying different syntax to achieve the same result in an attempt to hit upon a version of the logic that makes that version of Javascript happy.

Including JQuery and writing your function using Jquery syntax might be a solution, too. As JQuery itself seems pretty good at dealing with these differences.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For that wouldn't I need to also inject JQuery into the WebView? I'd really like to avoid that if I can.

Comment: I'm not sure you can even inject JQuery and get it to work. You'd need to have it included in the page itself.  I use it specifically for local HTML assets, so the page simply links to a local copy of JQuery min in the assets folder.  So, yeah, if this content is external I suppose JQuery is out.

Comment: Looking at the javascript I inject into webviews, my syntax is usually  webview.loadUrl("javascript: new function(){ ... }");  Perhaps just the different function declaration is enough to make Gingerbread happy.

Comment: The only way I've ever found to work out these issues is to add a WebChromeClient to your webview, override the onJsAlert, and then add alerts to your javascript.  When you debug, you should be able to see the onJsAlert being called and then it's just a matter of moving your alert until it stops firing.  Then you can at least figure out what specifically isn't working right in your function.

Comment: Although, you say the form is actually submitting...it seems your function is actually working OK.  If it was a true javascript syntax issue, the submit wouldn't be working, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, it's really strange. I'll try to add a few alerts and see if/where it's actually failing. Thanks again for the tips.

Comment: Are you loading that javascript after the WebViewClient onPageFinished fires?

Comment: I have it setup where the user can only click the Login button once the page has finished loading so the JS won't be injected unless it has reached the onPageFinished() code.

Answer (score 0):

At which point in your flow does the JavaScript URL get loaded? Are you certain that at this time the DOM is loaded and the elements you reference are valid?

Do you see anything output in logcat when trying to execute the JavaScript? That should show JavaScript errors.

Comment: I have the workflow setup to enable the button only once the page has finished loading so the JS won't be injected until the page has loaded. I also can see that the page has loaded in the WebView itself too. I haven't seen any JS errors in the log either unfortunately. I added some of the onPageFinished() code above. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Can you run any JavaScript when you click the button, or is it only that specific snippet that doesn't work? e.g. If you try to do a console.log or pop up alert dialog instead, does it work?

Comment: So after some more debugging it seems like the JS gets run but the 2.3.6 webview isn't storing some cookies properly which basically breaks the webview login completely, which is now a new problem. However, when calling the script, older versions of android must not render the text into the fields before the `submit` call is made. What I did was changed the JS to use `\"username\"` instead of `'username'` and also removed the `submit` call. Single quotes didn't seem to get recognized correctly, double quotes fixed that and removing the `submit` did indeed render the fields correctly.